# Activity entering on onCreate after changing orientation

Tags: android

I am having an issue I didn't use to have before.

I am using a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3, the problem I am having is that I have an Activity declared on the Manifest this way:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Authorization"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
    </activity>
```

So, when I change the orientation of the phone, it is entering again and again on the onCreate method!! As far as I know, if i write

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

the Activity shouldn't enter again on onCreate.....

Anyone knows what's happening??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you apply saveInsatnce in your onCreate?

Comment: No, I don't use it, but the point is that as far as I know, If I declare my Activity with android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize", it shouldn't enter on onCreate again....

Comment: How do you know that..It is going into onCreate()

Comment: Cause I have a breakpoint inside it and it is stopping there......

Comment: Does it happen in the emulator or other devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the activity shouldn't be entering onCreate method, as it's go against the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

But there's a configuration in the Developer Options of the phone that forces that wierd situation. It's not your code's fault.

The option is called "Don't keep activities" and it's intended to be used to test the behavior of your app when the activity is destroyed by the system (for instance, when it's running out of memory).

To change that, go to Configuration -> Developer Options and in the secion "Apps", uncheck "Don't Keep Activities".

Comment: I didn't even know I could do that on the Developer Options.....thanks to let me know! Anyway, it was unckecked already, so, the problem presists......I don't know what to do.... The funniest thing is that on the rest of the activities which are declared the same way, it is not happening!! I really don't understand why....

Comment: @zapotec, it's really weird.. have you checked the intent the second time the flow enters in onCreate method? Use getIntent() and paste here the actions and other properties, maybe we can see anything unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers Rusmus, Bhr and praven sharma,

As Rusmus said, on the Android documentation they explain that when you declare your Activity the flags I did, the Activity should call onConfigurationChanged method:

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

The point, is that it also says the following:

> Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not
>   restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to
>   onConfigurationChanged()

I really don't understand why on this mobile phone it is entering on onCreate, and instead on a Galaxy SII with Android 4.04 it is not happening. On my Samsung Galaxy SII it is not re-entering on onCreate() again and again with orientationChanges.

Thanks a lot!